# GCSToGCSOperator not moving files in same bucket

Tags: airflow, google-cloud-composer, airflow-2.x, airflow-taskflow

I am trying to move files from my "new" folder in my-bucket to "test" folder in the same bucket using GCSToGCSOperator, I am passing a list of files to the source bucket but when I run dag I don't see files moving. I used xcom push to get list of file names from the folder new in my bucket

```
def segregate_files(ti):
    source_bucket = "my-bucket"
    PROJECT_ID="project"
    destination_bucket = "my-bucket"
    
    
    source_files=ti.xcom_pull(task_ids='list_file')
    client = storage.Client(project=PROJECT_ID)
    bucket = client.get_bucket(source_bucket)
    
    
    
    print(source_files) #['new/abc.txt','new/bcd.txt','new/abc_bcd.txt']


    new_files = [file for file in data if 'abc' in file]
    print(new_files) #['new/abc.txt','new/abc_bcd.txt']
    
    
    if new_files:
        task_id = 'move_new_files'
        move_abc_files = GCSToGCSOperator(
            task_id=task_id,
            source_bucket=source_bucket,
            source_objects=new_files,
            destination_bucket=destination_bucket,
            destination_object="test/",
            move_object=True,
            dag=dag
        )

bucket_files = GCSListObjectsOperator(
        task_id='list_file',
        bucket='my-bucket',
        prefix='new/',
        delimiter='.txt',
        do_xcom_push=True,
        dag=dag
    )
```

Comment: This code is missing information to reproduce, e.g. the variable `data` is not defined in the given code. Also, I suspect you're continuously calling GCS to list objects? Note that Airflow periodically evaluates your code and this might result in the `move_new_files` appearing and disappearing. A better approach is to keep your DAG structure static by always defining the `move_new_files` task, and just have it not copy anything if there isn't any work to do.

Comment: Hi @avinash reddy,  I have posted a solution for your requirement . Do consider to upvoting and accepting if it helps, else let me know so that I can improve my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a workaround you can consider the below code as an example:

```
import os
from google.cloud import storage

source_bucket_name = 'my-bucket'
source_folder_name = 'new'
destination_bucket_name = 'my-bucket'
destination_folder_name = 'old'


def copy_files(ti):
    file_list=ti.xcom_pull(task_ids='listing_files')
    storage_client = storage.Client()
    source_bucket = storage_client.get_bucket(source_bucket_name)
    destination_bucket = storage_client.get_bucket(destination_bucket_name)

    for filename in file_list:
        source_blob = source_bucket.blob(f'{filename}')
        output_filename=os.path.basename(filename)
        destination_blob = destination_bucket.blob(f'{destination_folder_name}/{output_filename}')
        destination_blob.upload_from_string(source_blob.download_as_string())

    print(f'Files copied successfully.{file_list}')
    

with DAG(dag_id='final',start_date=datetime(2021, 4, 5, 15, 0),schedule_interval='@daily',catchup=False) as dag:
    t1 = BashOperator(task_id='started', bash_command='echo starting…')
    t2 = GoogleCloudStorageListOperator(task_id='listing_files',bucket='my-bucket',prefix='new/',delimiter='.txt')
    t3 = PythonOperator(task_id="copying_files",python_callable=copy_files)
    t4 = BashOperator(task_id='end', bash_command='echo end')

    t1>>t2>>t3>>t4
```

**DAG :**

[image]

NB: I tested the above code for txt  and py files. It worked fine for me.